# Show/hide password onClick of using Vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide/show password using the following codes which works fine if it is for 1 input field. If I have another input field, say for 'verify password', how do I make the other works. I'm kinda stuck here.

Any input is very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    var passwordField = document.querySelector(".password"),
        eyeIcon = document.querySelector(".icon");

    function togglePassword() {
        if (passwordField.type === "password") {
            passwordField.type = "text";
        } else {
            passwordField.type = "password";
        }
    }
    eyeIcon.addEventListener("click", togglePassword);
```

Comment: both will have their own eye icon?

Answer (score 0):

How about refactoring togglePassword() to handle a provided list of elements?

```
function togglePassword(fields = []) {
  fields.forEach(toggleType);
}

toggleType(field) {
  if(!field.type) {
    return;
  }

  if (field.type === "password") {
    field.type = "text";
  } else {
    field.type = "password";
  }
}
```

Then you can declare multiple fields at the top, and pass them into the function as an array (`togglePassword([passwordField, verifyField, ...])`).

Comment: I think there is an error on `toogleType(field)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: What error do you see?

(Admittedly, the above is just a snippet; I haven't tested the code)

Comment: ```toggleType(field) {
  if(!field.type) {
    return;
  }``` I couldn't rectify what the error is. My knowledge JS is pretty limited to be honest

Comment: Ah. Just a guard to protect against cases where `field.type` doesn't exist, and therefore shouldn't/couldn't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to toggle both at a time

```
var passwordField = 
document.getElementById('password');
var passwordField2 = 
document.getElementById('password2');

if (passwordField.type === "password") {                  
    passwordField.type = 'text';              
    passwordField2.type = 'text';              
} else {                               
    passwordField.type = 'password';         
    passwordField2.type = 'password';              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the `listener` function generic using `this`:

```
 var passwordField = document.querySelector(".password"),
        eyeIcon = document.querySelector(".icon");
  var anotherPassFeild = document.querySelector(".anotherPass")

    function togglePassword() {
        if (this.type === "password") {
            this.type = "text";
        } else {
            this.type = "password";
        }
    }
    passwordField.addEventListener("click", togglePassword);
    anotherPassFeild.addEventListener("click", togglePassword);
```

Or, you can give the same class name password to different inputs, select them all and attach the event listener to each of them like this.

```js
    var passwordField = document.querySelectorAll(".password");
    function togglePassword() {
        if (this.type === "password") {
            this.type = "text";
        } else {
            this.type = "password";
        }
    }
    passwordField.forEach((elem)=>{
      elem.addEventListener("click", togglePassword);
    })
```

```html
<input class ="password something" type="password"/>
<input class ="password icon" type="password"/>
```

Comment: Guess I need to use different class for icon too then

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, the event listener is attached to the input.  What if I want it be when the icon is clicked (like how it should be) NOT the input?

Comment: I'm assuming your `icon` is going to be there inside `input` field. Anyway, can you show your HTML? At most with slight adjustments you can make it work even in that case. With the `this` reference, you;ll have to find the corresponding `input` which could be it's parent or something.

Comment: The icon is just floated to the right of the input anyway. The thing is the code you have provided works in such a way that even on focus, the password field has been set to "text", meaning the user will see the password right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215001/discussion-between-rahul-dwivedi-and-yansusanto).